# Plotting a function defined by the user

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, plot

I'm trying to write a program on Python that would plot a function defined by the user on the entry box. I am using matplotlib with tkinter and I have a defined interval on x within I wish to plot the function defined by the user. The problem is how to get the function the user inputs and read it as a command. I'd like for instance, that when the user types y = x* *2 (or y = np.sin(x), etc.) on the entry, the command is understood as a logical expression instead of as a string "x**2" that will generate an error. Is there any way to do this? Any help is welcomed.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

LARGE_FONT=("Times New Roman",12)
x=np.linspace(-5,5,100)


class MyApp(tk.Tk):

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

       #tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self,default="myicon.ico") #to add icons
       tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "My app")
       container = tk.Frame(self)

       container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

       container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
       container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

       self.frames = {}

       for F in (StartPage, GraphPage):

           frame = F(container, self)

           self.frames[F] = frame

           frame.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky="nsew")

       self.show_frame(StartPage)

   def show_frame(self, cont):

       frame = self.frames[cont]
       frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

   def __init__(self,parent,controller):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)


       label = tk.Label(self,text="Ed. App - Start Page",font = LARGE_FONT)
       label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)


       button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Go to graph page ->", command = lambda:controller.show_frame(GraphPage))
       button3.pack()




class GraphPage(tk.Frame):

   def __init__(self,parent,controller):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

       e = Entry(self, width =50)
       e.pack()
       label = tk.Label(self,text="Graph your function!",font = LARGE_FONT)
       label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

       button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home", command = lambda:controller.show_frame(StartPage))
       button1.pack()

       f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
       a = f.add_subplot(111)

       def myClick():
          # y = e.get() i'd like something like this to work, instead of line below
           y = x**2
           a.plot(x,y,'r')
           canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
           canvas.draw()
           canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

           toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self)
           toolbar.update()
           canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
                   
              

       button4 = ttk.Button(self, text="plot", command = myClick)
       button4.pack()





       

app = MyApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use eval() on your desired input variable.

Example:

```
z=input()
print(eval(z))
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Just added y = eval(e.get()) and it worked like a gem!